# npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/service-worker@9.0.7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-service-worker

While generating docker image, after executing the command `npm install` i get this error

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/service-worker@9.0.7
```

However in my local computer it works just fine .

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989383/could-not-resolve-dependency-npm-err-peer-angular-compiler11-2-8

Comment: yes , unfortunately didn't help